# MediaMetadataRetriever on URLs (exoplayer)

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am using MediaMetadataRetriever to get data like width, height, rotation and first frame bitmap.

However,The setDataSource() method takes a lot of time due to which the resizing slows down. I also have to spend time in extracting the actual video to be played.

```
MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(
                    Uri.parse(mVideoFile),
                    dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
```

Is there a way to retrieve meta data from this videoSource?